# Using Pipes to read and write binary data in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, readfile, writefile, haskell-pipes

I am trying to read and write very many ints in constant memory. I have figured out how to write the ints to memory but have not figured out how to read them back.

```
import Control.Lens (zoom)
import System.IO (IOMode(..), withFile)
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB    
import qualified Pipes.Parse as P
import qualified Pipes.Binary as P

intStream :: Monad m => Proxy x' x () Int m b
intStream = go (0 :: Int) where
   go i = yield i >> go (i + 1)

decoder :: Monad m => Int ->  P.Parser P.ByteString m [Int]
decoder n = zoom (P.decoded . P.splitAt n) P.drawAll

main :: IO ()
main = do
    withFile "ints" WriteMode $ \h -> do
         runEffect $ for intStream P.encode >-> P.take 10000 >-> PB.toHandle h
    withFile "ints" ReadMode $ \h -> do
         xs <- P.evalStateT (decoder 10000000) (PB.fromHandle h)
         print xs
```

I got the decoder function from the documentation for [Pipes.Binary](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-binary-0.4.0.4/docs/Pipes-Binary.html). However it uses `drawAll` which according to the [documentation](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-2.19/pipes-parse-3.0.3/Pipes-Parse.html#v:drawAll) `drawAll` is not idiomatic use of Pipes and is provided for testing purposes.

My question is how to modify `decoder` so that it doesn't use `drawAll` and thus does not load all the values of `xs` into memory. So instead of printing the list of xs I could `P.map print` over a stream of decoded `ints` being read from the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs say that [`decoded`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-binary-0.4.0.4/docs/Pipes-Binary.html#v:decoded) is a lens from a stream of bytes to a stream of decoded values. We can get the latter out of the former using `view` from `lens`:

```
decoder :: Monad m => Int -> Producer P.ByteString m a -> Producer Int m ()
decoder n p = void (view P.decoded p) >-> P.take n

main :: IO ()
main = do
    withFile "ints" WriteMode $ \h -> do
         runEffect $ for intStream P.encode >-> P.take 10000 >-> PB.toHandle h
    withFile "ints" ReadMode $ \h -> do
         runEffect $ decoder 10000 (PB.fromHandle h) >-> P.print
```

I don't have much experience with `pipes`, I just followed the types here. The program seems to function as intended though.

Comment: I try to follow the types but sometimes it gets difficult when the types start looking like alphabet soup ;)